# Integration of files with MAC in Python (Related to Cryptography)

Tags: python, cryptography, key, password-protection, mac-address

So I have this assignment of password-protecting public and private keys and then ensuring the integrity of these files with MAC. However, I do not understand what **integrity with MAC** means?

[image: Assignment]

This is my code so far:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import scrypt
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
import os

#Generate a public/private key pair for the certificate authority. The public key of the CA is self-signed.
def generateCAkeys():
    password = b'super secret'

    # Generating public/private key pair using RSA
    key = RSA.generate(2048)

    # Salting the password
    password = b'super secret'
    salt = get_random_bytes(16)
    salted_password = scrypt(password, salt, 16, N=2**14, r=8, p=1)

    # Saving the salted password into a file
    file_out = open("password.bin", "wb")
    file_out.write(salted_password)
    file_out.close()

    # Saving private key into a file, protected by the salted password
    encrypted_private_key = key.export_key(passphrase=salted_password, pkcs=8,
                                protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
    out = os.path.join("keystore", "private_key.bin")
    file_out = open(out, "wb")
    file_out.write(encrypted_private_key)
    file_out.close()

    # Saving public key into a file, protected by the salted password
    encrypted_private_key = key.publickey().export_key(passphrase=salted_password, pkcs=8,
                                protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
    out = os.path.join("keystore", "public_key.bin")
    file_out = open(out, "wb")
    file_out.write(encrypted_private_key)
    file_out.close()

    print(key.publickey().export_key())

    return
```

Comment: Pointer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption

Comment: public keys are not secrets and don't need to be encrypted.